# How do I fix Error: export 'firestore' (imported as 'firestore') was not found?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to connect my google firebase project to my react one. I am using [this guide here](https://www.makeuseof.com/react-app-firebase-connect/), but whenever I run it, I get an error saying

```
export 'firestore' (imported as 'firestore') was not found in '../firebase_setup/firebase' (module has no exports)
```

My code looks like this:

```
import '@firebase/auth'
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
```

And I also have the handlesubmit file as suggested in the tutorial I'm following:

```
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

import '@firebase/auth'
import getFirestore from "firebase/firestore"; 
import { addDoc, collection } from "@firebase/firestore"
import { firestore } from "../firebase_setup/firebase"
```

I tried using
`import * as firebase from './firebase';`

but it gets greyed out in Visual Studio , saying 'firebase' is declared but its value is never read.

Comment: In order to `import` something from another file, you need to `export` it there. You're not exporting `firestore`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following steps to create a react app with modular Firebase JS SDK:

- npx create-react-app my-app
- cd my-app
- npm start (verify that the app is running fine)
- npm install firebase (check package.json file and see that firebase is listed under dependencies)
- open App.js file and use the following codes to import firebase SDKs:

> ```
> import {initializeApp} from 'firebase/app' 
> import {getFirestore} from 'firebase/firestore'
>
> const firebaseConfig = {
>   ...  
> };
>  
> const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
> const firebaseFirestore = getFirestore();
> ```